# Remplezar etiquetas <div> por <p> en php conservando clases y/o estilos

Tags: php, str-replace

Hola amigos tengo esta duda

como etiquetas `<div>` por `<p>` en php
pero...

tengo etiquetas `<div>` que tienen clases y/o estilos que si quiero conservar con su respectivo cierre `</div>`

intente asi pero me elimina el `</div>` que si quiero conservar

```
str_replace('<div>', '<p>', $body);
str_replace('</div>', '</p>', $body);
```

este es mi codigo

```
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div>
    <div class="media_embed">
            <div style="xxx">
                <div style="xxx">
                    <div style="xxx"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

quisiera que quedara asi:

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
<p>
    <div class="media_embed">
            <div style="xxx">
                <div style="xxx">
                    <div style="xxx"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
```

solo quiero conservar los `divs` que tengan clase o style con su cierre `</div>`

me podrian ayudar por favor

Comment: intentastes str_replace('<div ', '<p ', $body);

Comment: @skycomputer2 para que quieres remplazar?, publica tu codigo html porfavor

Comment: Creo que tratar de imitar la lógica de un parser HTML, o de cualquier lenguaje similar a XML, a punta de str_replace y preg_replace es en vano. Para eso existen parseadores específicos y ninguno consiste en un par de líneas.

Comment: No te va a ser tan fácil,ya que el cierre, no puedes hacer distinción entre uno y otro

Comment: La respuesta que se da como duplicada no sirve ya que no copia los atributos. En cuanto se abra te pongo código de cómo se copian los atributos tras reemplazar una etiqueta por otra.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) la cual soporta expresiones regulares:

```
$html = "<div class='caso-1'>Texto dentro del div</div>";

$html = preg_replace('/div/', 'p', $html);
var_dump(htmlentities($html));
//resulta: string(52) "<p class='caso-1'>Texto dentro del p</p>"

$html1 = "<div class='caso-2' style='align-content: center'>Texto dentro del div</div>";

$div = array('/\<div(.*)>/', '/\<\/div>/');
$html1 = preg_replace($div, array('<p$1>', '</p>'), $html1);
var_dump(htmlentities($html1));
//resulta: string(84) "<p class='caso-2' style='align-content: center'>Texto dentro del div</p>"
```

Como puedes observar, la primera opción reemplaza todos los casos en los que encuentre el texto `div` la segunda opción ya es más pulida, pero puedes buscar una expresión regular diferente

Comment: ya lo probe pero el problema es que las etiquetas div que tienen clases y estilos me las cambia por p y esas si las quiero convervar.

Comment: con este código le pasas la clase y el estilo a un elemento p. Lo que el OP necesita es omitir del reemplazo los div que tengan clase o estilo. La complicación es pillar a qué div pertenece cada /div

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias alternativias.

**La mejor opción sería utilizar un parseador de HTML.**

Dicho esto, si quieres seguir usando expresiones regulares, tienes estas dos opciones:

**Opción 1:**

Utiliza la siguiente expresión regular `<div>([^<]*?)<\/div>` y reemplaza por `<p>$1</p>`

Esta es la opción más sencilla, pero sólamente te funcionará en el caso de no tener tags html anidados y también con la condición de que dentro del texto no encuentres el caracter '<'.

Es decir, estos dos casos no funcionarían:

```
<div> <span>hola</span> </div>
<div> 3<4 </div>
```

Pero sí que funcionaría con el ejemplo que has puesto. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W1hTTH/1/).

**Opción 2:**

Este método lo utilizaremos para evitar la limitación anterior. Mediante un bucle y una expresión regular recursiva, iremos haciendo sustituciones.

La expresión regular es la siguiente `<div>((?:<div[^>]*>(?1)<\/div>|[^<]*|<(?!div))*)<\/div>` (flags: m,s,i) y reemplaza por `<p>$1</p>` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XfLuew/4/)

Sin embargo esto sustituirá un único nivel en caso de encontrar etiquetas anidadas. Por ejemplo si tu entrada es:

```
<div><div>hola</div></div>
```

Lo cambiará a

```
<p><div>hola</div></p>
```

Con lo que deberás ejecutarlo una vez más para obtener:

```
<p><p>hola</p></p>
```

Básicamente repites la sustitución hasta que el string anterior sea igual al nuevo (significa que no hay nada adicional por reemplazar)

Aquí tienes un ejemplo montado con php:

```
<?php

$prevhtml = '
<div class="foo">
<div>FOO</div>

  <div class="bar">
     <div>BAR</div>
  </div>

  <div>FOOBAR<div class="foobar"></div></div>

  <div class="bar"><div><b>BAR</b></div></div>

  <!-- para este caso, deberás ejecutar preg_replace 
       hasta que no haya nada nuevo por reemplazar -->
  <div><div>foobar</div></div>
</div>

';

$newhtml = '';
while($newhtml != $prevhtml) {
    if (!empty($newhtml)) $prevhtml = $newhtml;
    $newhtml = preg_replace(
         '/<div>((?:<div[^>]*>(?1)<\/div>|[^<]*|<(?!div))*)<\/div>/smi'
        ,'<p>$1</p>'
        ,$prevhtml);
}

print $newhtml;
```

También tienes el código [aquí](https://www.ideone.com/4H7kdj) para que lo veas en ejecución.